# Issue with stopping weblogic server using wls-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

This is part of my pom.xml of my .ear file

```
<plugin>

    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <adminurl>${adminURL}</adminurl>
    <user>${username}</user>
    <password>${pswrd}</password>
    <upload>true</upload>
    <remote>false</remote>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
    <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
    <targets>${serverName}</targets>
    <noExit>true</noExit>
    <middlewareHome>${middlewareH}</middlewareHome>
    <domainHome>${domainH}</domainHome>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>stopserver</id>
    <phase>install</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>stop-server</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    <action>stopserver</action>
    <workingDir>${stopScriptDirectory}</workingDir>
    <command>stopScript.sh</command>

    </configuration>
    </execution>

    </executions>

</plugin>
```

I am trying to stop the server by running the stopScript.sh

This is the error I am getting when it is trying to execute the stop-server goal:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.1.0:stop-server (stopserver) on project OventusEAR2: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.oracle.weblogic:wls-maven-plugin:12.1.1.0:stop-server for parameter command: Cannot assign configuration entry 'command' with value 'stopScript.sh' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.lang.String[]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not familiar with this particular plugin, however I have seen similar issues before, I guess ***command*** parameter is expecting an array instead.

Please try replacing

> ```
>    <command>stopScript.sh</command>
> ```

with

```
    <command>
      <value>stopScript.sh</value>
    </command>
```

and test again.

Comment: That did the trick. The solution that worked for me was <command><value>./stopScript.sh</value></command>